# QEMU-KVM vs VMWare for kernel debugging with GDB

Tags: linux, gdb, qemu, kvm, vmware-workstation

I have been using QEMU-KVM and GDB for hacking the Linux Kernel. I ran into some situations where reverse debugging will be useful. QEMU doesn't seem to  support reverse debugging, but I heard VMWare does (http://lwn.net/Articles/356332/).

What are the pros and cons of VMWare + GDB compared to QEMU + GDB? Are there any pitfalls I would run into by switching from QEMU to VMWare?

Answer (score 0):

VMware dropped support for reversible/replay debugging some years ago.

There are some patches to QEMU for reversible debugging, but AFAIK not yet merged: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/qemu-devel/2014-11/msg03947.html

You can use UndoDB (http://undo-software.com/) for reversible debugging of userspace, but not kernel.

I'd imagine those patches are your best bet, but I don't think there is a particularly easy solution.

Greg